# Is it possible to exit if user input negative number

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop, foreach, break

Upon executing the below program in C#, the program is not compiling, any hints to fix the mistakes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int input;
        Console.WriteLine("Input a number:");
        int input=Console.ReadLine();
        while (true)
        {
            input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (input <= 0) break;
        }​

        Console.Write("Your input: ");
        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write(number + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to initialise the variable `input` twice, in lines 7 and also 9. This will prevent your code from compiling.

Also it looks like the variable `numbers` is not initialised anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

yes, sure you cant declare in the same scope 2 variables with the same name:

your int input is the reason am talking about

```
int input;  //    <----
Console.WriteLine("Input a number:");
int input=Console.ReadLine();  //   <---
```

Comment: What is your suggestion ?

Comment: That works for me but the idea is that I should store the input user to List then print that List when the program breaks if user enter negative input.

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables with the same name, which this is wrong.

```
int input;
int input=Console.ReadLine();
```

Also you aren't saving the user inputs, input variable save the last input the user put. It always have one value.
You have to declare numbers before using it and storing the user inputs in it to print them in foreach loop.

declare **input** once as int then use it without **re**declaring it. Also declare **numbers** as list of int and in while loop make this:

```
input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (input <= 0) 
    {break;}
else
    {numbers.add(input);}
```

To save the first user input outside while loop do this:

```
int input;
Console.WriteLine("Input numbers:");//As you expect the user to input more than one number
input=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if(input > 0)
{numbers.add(input);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be what you want:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string inputText;
        int input;
        var numbers = new List<int>();
        string inputNumbers = "";
        bool negativeInserted = false;
        while (negativeInserted == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input a number:");
            inputText = Console.ReadLine();
            input = Convert.ToInt32(inputText);
            if (input >= 0)
            {
                numbers.Add(input);
            }
            else
            {
                negativeInserted = true;
            }
        }
        if (numbers.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var number in numbers)
            {
                if (numbers.Count == 1)
                {
                    inputNumbers = inputNumbers + number.ToString();
                }
                else if (numbers.Count > 1 && number != numbers.Last())
                {
                    inputNumbers = inputNumbers + number.ToString() + ",";
                }
                else if (number == numbers.Last())
                {
                    inputNumbers = inputNumbers + number.ToString() + "!";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inputNumbers = "Input number is negative!";
        }

        Console.Write("Your input numbers:" + inputNumbers);
        
        Console.Read();
    }
```

First mistake: you declared int input twice.
Second: You can't set Console.Readline() value to int variable because it returns as string.
Third: numbers is not initialised anywhere and there is no need. Forth: use return instead of break.

Comment: That works for me but the idea is that I should store the input user to List then print that List when the program breaks if user enter negative input.

Comment: @Musta_Jaguaari it is a bit late but updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

That works for me but the idea is that I should store the input user to List then print that List when the program breaks if user enter negative input. Here is the code which I build after your help guys. It is almost done but the list of stored input is not printed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int input;
    start:
        Console.Write("Input a number: ");
        string inputText = Console.ReadLine();
        input = Convert.ToInt32(inputText);
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        numbers.Add(input);
        while (input >= 0)
        {
            goto start;
        }
        while (input < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.Write("Your input: ");
        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write(number + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The program should print all the positive list numbers after it breaks due to inputing negative number